# MySQL Syntax Error - END IF line

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create a stored procedure with an if statement within.
I copied from: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html

But I get the following error exact on the END IF; near '':

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `myProc`; 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `myProc`(
   IN in_userId int,
   IN in_projectId int
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE tmp_courseId int;
    DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cursorProjectCourse CURSOR FOR SELECT CourseId FROM XC_PROJECT_COURSE where projectId = in_projectId ;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cursorProjectCourse;

    read_loop: LOOP

        FETCH FROM cursorProjectCourse INTO tmp_courseId;

        IF done = 1 THEN LEAVE read_loop;

        END IF;

        SELECT tmp_courseId, in_userId; 
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursorProjectCourse;
END;
```

Has anyone an idea where I make a mistake?

Exact error message:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 19 SQL Error

MySQL Version:
5.5.46

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.
I have to set `DELIMITER $$` at first statement and at the end `DELIMITER ;`

```
DELIMITER $$;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `myProc`; $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `myProc`(
   IN in_userId int,
   IN in_projectId int
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE tmp_courseId int;
    DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cursorProjectCourse CURSOR FOR SELECT CourseId FROM XC_PROJECT_COURSE where projectId = in_projectId ;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cursorProjectCourse;

    read_loop: LOOP

        FETCH FROM cursorProjectCourse INTO tmp_courseId;

        IF done = 1 THEN LEAVE read_loop;

        END IF;

        SELECT tmp_courseId, in_userId; 
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursorProjectCourse;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

> **It is important to set the keyword on the first position in line**. If there is a blank on the first position, the error above will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are missing the loop label while ending loop. Change it to below

```
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH FROM cursorProjectCourse INTO tmp_courseId;
    IF done = 1 THEN 
    LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
END LOOP read_loop;
    SELECT tmp_courseId, in_userId;
```

Comment: I tried also other solutions to position the END IF statement (like the same line etc.) but it is still not working.

Comment: @NorbertKoch, disregard previous answer ... see edit now. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution above. After this it works with both syntax: `END LOOP;` and `END LOOP read_loop;`